# java classes creating from xsd via xjc problem

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

i have the xsd file created and worced fine in VS. But now we need to create java classes corresponding to this. I tryed to use standard xjc tool from the JDK 1.6 but it give me an error 
[ERROR] ct-props-correct.4: Error for type '#AnonType_BathRoomApartmentType'. Du
plicate attribute uses with the same name and target namespace are specified.  N
ame of duplicate attribute use is 'Changed'.
  line 314 of file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/temp/LogicalModelSch
ema.xsd

even thoughts i was able to generate the XML files from this xsd in Eclipse with no problems.

Could someone give me any suggestion how i can handle this?
I looked in the forum but didn't find any solution for now!

Thanks in advance,
Mila

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, XJC requires help from you because by default it wants to map two different things in the XSD to the same Java class or field.  In this case, it's something about "Changed" in BathRoomApartment - there's another "Changed" that's colliding with it.  You'll need to provide some binding customization, or change the schema (if possible) to fix it.